# One ASP.Net ImageButton not working in Chrome (but another is... and both work in IE 9)

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, imagebutton

One of my image buttons is not working in Chrome, but the other button is (they both work in IE 9):

**Not working**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="lblCustomer" 
    ImageUrl="~/images/Customer.jpg" 
    runat="server" 
    onmouseover="this.src='images/Customer.jpg';" 
    onmouseout="this.src='images/Customer.jpg';" 
    AlternateText="Customer" 
    CausesValidation="false" 
    OnClick="ibtnCustomer_Click" 
    ToolTip="Customer" />
```

**Working:**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnUnRegisteredVendor" 
    ImageUrl="images/VendorButton.jpg" 
    runat="server" 
    onmouseover="this.src='images/VendorButtonHover.jpg';" 
    onmouseout="this.src='images/VendorButton.jpg';" 
    AlternateText="Vendor" 
    CausesValidation="false" 
    OnClick="btnUnRegisteredProvider_Click" 
    ToolTip="" />
```

The Customer button is not clickable in Chrome.
Any idea why the Customer button would not work in Chrome?

**Update:**

The rendered HTML from Chrome is:

```
<div id="Customer" style="width: 100%; left: 5px;">
    <input type="image" name="Master$cphMainContent$lblCustomer" id="cphMainContent_lblCustomer" title="Customer" onmouseover="this.src=&#39;images/Customer.jpg&#39;;" onmouseout="this.src=&#39;images/Customer.jpg&#39;;" src="images/Customer.jpg" alt="Customer" />
</div>


<div id="VendorsButton">
  <input type="image" name="Master$cphMainContent$ibtnVendor" id="cphMainContent_ibtnVendor" title="Vendor log in, registration or access without registration" onmouseover="this.src=&#39;images/VendorsButtonHover.jpg&#39;;" onmouseout="this.src=&#39;images/VendorsButton.jpg&#39;;" src="images/VendorsButton.jpg" alt="Vendors" />
<div id="VendorFeaturesContainer">
```

Comment: Silly, but did you try without the tooltip? It is the only difference that I see at first glance.

Comment: Would you post the actual HTML rendered by the ImageButton by viewing the HTML source of the .aspx page in a browser?

Comment: Also as a side note, consider using CSS sprites instead of javascript for your hover styles.  This is more performant and may help reduce any cross-browser issues dealing with Javascript: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: @MikeC please see updated post with html code.

Comment: You could try jquery if you are open to that technology. VERY easy and pain free.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you have a different path to both of them. Try changing the first one's `ImageUrl` to `"images/Customer.jpg"`

Comment: @DotNetRookie what exactly is the error/problem you're getting?

Comment: wow..... didn't realize I didn't mention that. The button "lblCustomer" is not an imagebutton in Chrome. Meaning I can't click it to make anything happen.

Comment: the Customer_Click code is     Server.Transfer("CustomerLogin.aspx");

Answer (score 0):

If the previous suggestion didn't work, you may have problems with the ~/ shortcut in a virtual directory

Answer (score 0):

When a control (asp:ImageButton) is part of a "Content Placeholder" for an ASPX Master 
Page, the ../  and ~/  are interpreted differently by IE11 versus Chrome.

IE will respond as expected with the prefix ~/ to represent the root directory of the web application.  IE is looking for the image directory (ImageUrl="~/images/Customer.jpg") one level down from the root.

In Chrome, the file inserted into the Master Page will respond as expected when using the ../ prefix when your images are in a directory at the same level as your "content ASPX file".  Chrome is interpreting ~/ to be in the same directory as the "content ASPX file".  That is, Chrome is looking for your image directory as a sub-directory of the directory holding your "content ASPX file".

The asp:ImageButton isn't amenable to a javascript function as far as I know.  One work around is to have two image directories (where IE expects it, and where Chrome expects it) with the appropriate jpg, png, gif, et al files.

Comment: One of my projects uses SkinID that works in both IE and Chrome (rather than the ImageURL attribute).

        </asp:ImageButton>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAddNew" Style="z-index: 102; left: 261px; top: 70px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
            font-size: 9pt; position: absolute;" runat="server" Text="Add New" 
            SkinID="ImgbtnAddNewPart" ToolTip="Parts Management" TabIndex="7">

Comment: My web app server is IIS7 (Windows Server).  When I changed my slashes, the images were picked up by both IE and Chrome.  Windows directory\subdirectory versus URLs and Linx directory/subdirectory  
<br/>
ImageUrl="~/includes/img/btn_cancel.gif" OKay in IE, not Chrome
<br />
ImageUrl="../includes/img/btn_cancel.gif"  OKay in Chrome, not IE
<br/>
ImageUrl="..\includes\img\btn_cancel.gif"  OKay in both